# Is the SecurityContextCallableProcessingInterceptor thread safe?

Tags: spring-security

Looking through the source code of the SecurityContextCallableProcessingInterceptor (written by @Rob Winch, see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/context/request/async/SecurityContextCallableProcessingInterceptor.java)), I noticed that the interceptor copied the SecurityContext from one thread to the other, but did so using a member variable.  I understand why this is necessary as the callbacks for this interface happen on different threads.

Thinking about how other interceptors work (like HandlerInterceptors), usually a single instance serves all the requests.  Is that the case here?  If it is, is this thread safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SecurityContextCallableProcessingInterceptor` is not ThreadSafe. A new instance must be created for every Thread.  This is done automatically with the [WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4.0.1.RELEASE/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/context/request/async/WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java#L49)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  I did not notice a DeferredResult equivalent of this.  Is there a reason for that?

Comment: From the reference "There is no automatic integration with a DeferredResult that is returned by controllers. This is because DeferredResult is processed by the users and thus there is no way of automatically integrating with it. However, you can still use Concurrency Support to provide transparent integration with Spring Security." http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-async